# Is S a submanifold of M in this case?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Assume M is a manifold, S is a subset of M. If to any point x of S, there is an open set U in M s.t. U$\cap$S is an sub manifold of U, then S is a submanifold of M?

I arose this question from: To prove the regular value theorem,  It is enough to show that for every point a of $f^{-1}$(c) there is a neighborhood U of a such that U ∩ $f^{−1}$(c) is a submanifold of U of dimension m − n (where c is the regular point).

Comment: I guess that the answer is affirmative if $M$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: If $S$ is a union of pairwise disjoint submanifolds of $M$ of different dimension then $S$ won't be a submanifold in the most commonly accepted sense of the term. E.g., $S = \{0\} \cup (1, 2) \subseteq \mathbb{R} = M$.

Comment: @RobArthan, @ Giuseppe Negro, I arose this question from: To prove the regular value theorem,  It is enough to show that for every point a of $f^{−1}$(c) there is a neighborhood U of a such that U ∩ $f^{−1}$(c) is a submanifold of U of dimension m − n (where c is the regular point).